# Automatic selection of colored regions when digitzing choropleth maps

Tags: qgis, layers, digitizing, choropleth

I am new to working with GIS. I have a raster choropleth map similar to the one displayed below. I want to create a shapefile from the map, where each layer contains all the countries that have the same color. In this example, Brazil and Argentina would be in the same layer. Is there a way to automatically select all the regions that have the same color? Alternatively, can I select an area that is enclosed by the black lines, e.g. Brazil? In photoshop, there is a "quick-selection" tool that does this. I am using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Is it a raster- or a shapefile?

Comment: It's a raster, I want to create a shapefile based on the raster that I have.

Answer (score 2):

First follow this tutorial to convert raster to vector in QGIS.
http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html

Next make selections on the shapefile, based on the attribute values of the countries.

Finally export the selection.